# How to push a non fast-forward branch after some modification?

Tags: git

I have done a commit (`52c65fa`) with some changes that were to very linked to the branch. Then I have merged the master into the branch for solving conflicts (`544c9d9`) and then I have created a pull request. For approving the pull request, I need to remove that commit (`52c65fa`). I have thought to do another branch and move it there, using `cherry-pick`. I have fixed the conflicts in the file that was changed in the `52c65fa` commit. I have now arrived at something like:

```
*   28d0bd3 (HEAD, feat/error_hierarchy) Solved conflicts
|\  
| | * 0b4436d (feat/config_file_review) the branch that I wanted with copied commit
| | | *   544c9d9 (origin/feat/error_hierarchy) Resolved conflicts (old)
| | | |\  
| | |_|/  
| |/| |   
| * | |   cafe7d7 (origin/dev, dev) Merged in feat/follow_photo (pull request #10)
| |/ /  
| | * 52c65fa the commit that I've copied
| |/  
|/|   
* | 82e24f5 some other commits
|/  
*   e534410 Merged in feat/logs_work (pull request #9)
```

I have done a

```
git reset --hard 82e24f5
git merge dev
```

and now I am at `28d0bd3`. My problem is that now I want to do a `push`, but it is saying that it is not `fast-forward`. So **How to remove `544c9d9` and `52c65fa`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push even if it's not a fast-forward, using

```
git push -f origin myBranch
```

However, make sure that it's actually what you want to do, and that you won't overwrite distant commits you care about, as they may likely no longer be reachable by a branch.